# Floating Button showed too low - placed in CoordinatorLayout with android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"

Tags: android, floating-action-button

my floating action button shows up too low, even though it looks just fine in the Android Studio preview (see below).

FB is placed in root under CoordinatorLayout and set to show at the bottom end using android:layout_gravity.

This Layout is used in Fragment (extends Fragment) with Tabbed Activity using ViewPager. Android X.

Thanks

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout 
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/fragmentTableCoordinator"
    tools:context=".fragment.FragmentTable">
<!-- CoordinatorLayout for Floating Button -->

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/fragmentTable"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/colorBackgroundCards">

        <!-- Total Card -->
        <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
            android:id="@+id/card_viewNew"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            card_view:cardCornerRadius="2dp"
            card_view:contentPadding="10dp"
            card_view:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            card_view:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            card_view:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">


            <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">

                <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
                    android:id="@+id/Total_guideline"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    card_view:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.5" />

                    <!-- some textViews here -->
             

            </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

        </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>


        <!-- RecyclerView with months -->
        <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/Total_recycler_view"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:scrollbars="vertical"
            android:visibility="visible"
            card_view:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            card_view:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            card_view:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/card_viewNew" />

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

    <!-- Floating button -->
    <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/floating_button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
        android:contentDescription="TODO"
        app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_email" />

</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

My own fix : after hours trying to fix in in Fragment Layout - the best for me worked :

- place Floating button into activity_main layout
- hide it (setVisibility) for Fragment you dont need.
  This solved this for me

Answer (score 0):

You're setting `ConstraintLayout` inside the `CoordinatorLayout` and also `CoordinatorLayout` in the `Fragment` layout. You'll need to change it a bit.

Use `FloatingActionButton` inside your main activity layout with `CoordinatorLayout`, `AppBarLayout` and maybe a `NestedScrollView`, use `ConstraintLayout` in your `Fragment` layout and then, as you already mentioned, you'll be able to see `FloatingActionButton` with desire effect which is also stable at the bottom of the page and then you can hide it in the `Fragment`s you don't want to use.